# Using a predefined account for YouTube upload widget

Tags: html, youtube, web, widget, uploader

I want to build in a YouTube Upload Widget in my Website. The Widget itself works, but every user has to login with his own account. That's not what I want. I want the user to login as a user which already exists, so the videos were uploaded direct to a specific chanel which was already created.
Or is it possible to force the user to upload the video to a specific chanel? So he could login with his own account.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3):

I've been searching around for the same but it looks like it isn't possible.

You might want to look at [YouTube Direct Lite](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/). It's similar to the Upload Widget but allows your users to upload to your channel, into a 'moderation' area, where you can preview the videos before they go live. It's meant more for community use but I don't see why you couldn't repurpose it.

Remember that giving random strangers (or even relatively 'trusted' users) the ability to upload videos to your account could result in your account being shut down if any of those videos violate the YouTube T&Cs (hence the moderation step above). If that happens you're done. YouTube notoriously won't reopen closed accounts. You are 100% responsible for all videos on your channel.

Answer (score 0):

There is a demo on the developers site with the widget. Not sure if this is officially supported.

Here's the link to the demo:
https://www.youtube.com/yt/dev/demos.html#/upload

> Note: Looks like the webcam uploads has been deprecated; you can upload a file through the wdget or choose your youtube videos